# How do I display each element or alphabet as dash after it matches the input for Hangman?

Tags: python, python-3.9

I have been on and off programming but recently I have been more active and done some basic projects. However I have been stuck on this particular problem for the past 3 weeks and still cannot seems to solve it. Looked through some codes and tried and only could improve some parts. The bottom is my full code.

The problems that I faced is the one that I have stated in my title, I need to display the mystery word as dashes and when I guess the unknown word, it was suppose to appear as the only word. One issue is when I guess the word correctly, it only display the single alphabet and reset immediately.

```
import random

    word_list =[
    "SAXOPHONE",
    "THEREMIN",
    "XYLOPHONE",
    "TROMBONE",
    "RECORDER",
    "OCARINA",
    "HANG",
    "GUITAR",
    "PIANO",
    "DIDGERIDOO",
    "CELLO",
    "CLARINET",
    "BONGO",
    "DRUM",
    "FLUTE",
    "ERHU",
    "DIZI",
    "HARMONICA",
    "GONG",
    "GUZHENG"
    ]


pick_word = random.choice(word_list)
pick_letter = list(pick_word)
print(pick_letter)

print("Welcome to Hangman Instrumental")


turns = 10

while turns > 0:

      # input of players(input to accept both lower and upper case)
       player_in = input(str("\nEnter a Character: ")).upper()
  
      # check if input is the same as the pick letter
       if player_in in pick_letter:
              if player_in in pick_letter:
                      print(player_in)

              
        elif len(player_in) != 1:
                 print("Invalid input please try again")

        
        else:
                turns -= 1
                print("You have ",turns, " turns left")
                if turns == 0:
                print("You Lose !")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a list of all the player's guesses.  When you start a new game, set `all_guesses` to  `[]` and then, reading the letter from the console set:

```
all_guesses.append(player_in)
```

Now you can display just letters from that list in the secret word with:

```
display_word = ''
for c in pick_word:
    if c in all_guesses:
        display_word += c
    else:
        display_word += '-'
```

Then print out `display_word` however you like.  You can combine all of that into a single Python expression:

```
display_word = ''.join(c if c in all_guesses else '-' for c in pick_word)
```

That uses three ideas that you may not have seen yet (if-else expressions, generator expressions and the `.join()` string member function) so if it looks like Martian to you, that's okay.  Think of it as a peek ahead into cool things you'll learn later.